# Proper method for partial update of a subdocument in mongo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a collection in monogoDB with the following document structure:

```
{_id:"foo",
content: [
    {_id: "bar1",
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2",
    field3: "value3",
    field4: "value4"},        
    {_id: "bar2",
    field1: "value5",
    field2: "value6",
    field3: "value7",
    field4: "value8"}] 
}
```

I want to perform a partial update in a single embedded content document without having to specify which fields I am updating. From what I have read, my only option for doing this is:

```
Update({"_id": "foo", "content._id" : "bar1"}, 
       {"$set": {"content.$.field1" : "value9", "content.$.field2" : "value10"})
```

Assuming this is infact my best option, what is the best way to apply updates from a POST body? (I'm doing this in go). I don't think it makes sense to have the client prefix all of the field names with "content.$.", so right now I am creating a new map with the prefixed fields after receiving the POST body:

```
content := bson.M{}
json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&content)

newContent := bson.M{}

for key, val := range content{
    newContent["content.$." + key] = val
}

//proceed with newContent
```

but this feels like a hack. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A few lines of code to convert from one format to another does not seem like a hack to me.

Comment: mgo aligns very closely to what we can do directly with mongocli. So what you have done seems a viable solution to me.